# jQuery if statement - More than one character or focus

Tags: jquery

I have this code but am not why it isn't working.

I have an input which shows some text. I want this text to show when one of either the following criteria has been met:

- There is more than one character
- The input is in focus.

Currently only the first point works, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EopdYq) to the codepen demo and actual code below

HTML

```
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password">
<span class="show">SHOW</span>
```

CSS

```
.show {
   font-size: 14px;
   display: none;
   transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('input').on('input', function(){
            if ($(this).val().length > 0), ($(this).is(":focus")) {
                $(this).siblings('.show').fadeIn();
            } else {
                  $(this).siblings('.show').fadeOut();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your `if` statement isnt using valid syntax

Comment: The comma operator in your `if` statement will discard the first value and use only `($(this).is(":focus")`. Did you mean `||` instead?

Comment: @jsheeran yes that's what I meant but even that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that your `if` statement is not using valid JS syntax. You need to include a logical operator between the statements; they are not separate arguments.

To achieve your requirements you should split the events in to two, an `input` to check the length of the value, and a `focus` to know when the `input` is in use.

Also note that you should remove the `transition` rule from your CSS as it will interfere with the jQuery animation. Try this:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.show')[$(this).val().length > 0 ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();
});

$('input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.show').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.show {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password">
<span class="show">SHOW</span>
```